# NoSuchMethodError with SLF4J API

Tags: java, slf4j

When Use with slf4j,

```
String test = blahblahblah;
logger.info("{}",test);
```

Trace as below

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;

at org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.info(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:304)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Looks like you have a version mis-match between the various SLF4J API and integration libraries. SLF4J is extremely twitchy when it comes to version compatibility (e.g. 1.6.x is not backwards compatible with 1.5.x).

Make sure the various JAR versions match, and make sure there are no duplicate JARs on the classpath.

Comment: I had similar issues, but when i matched sl4j, sl4j-log4j version to 1.7.5 in my case it worked fine.

Comment: This dealt with the problem I had too. In the event that you're dealing with an old-school Web service on an external Java application server, you might try checking the app server's logs for suggestions of the slf4j binding versions that it will accept. E.g. catalina.out told me that I needed to provide a slf4j binding jar in the 1.6.x or 1.7.x ranges.

Answer (score 9):

I was getting this error:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
.
.
.
```

Now I just commented line with version from pom.xml, as shown below, and it is working now:

```
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <!-- <version>1.6.5</version> -->
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you guess what error you get when you don't provide a version number?

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure if you deploy in Glassfish externally (not locally) to remove duplicate dependencies in the lib folder of the Glassfish installation on that server.

In my case, everything worked fine locally but once deployed on a server I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have a different version of the MessageFormatter class than your JDK14LoggerAdapter class. Control your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that this is because of uncompatible version, like (if you are running your application 6.0 and holding a jar file (slf4j 1.5) or holding both (slf4j 1.5 and 1.6)) then exception might raised.

suggestion is 
go for proper version
dont place more than one version file (slf4f 1.5 and slf4j 1.6) file in the build path, delete the appropriate one

and

then run sure, you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,  we are having correct version match between the various SLF4J API and integration libraries. But we are also using `tika-app` jar, which also have SLF4J classes wrapped inside it.

To check if you are also having some (fat)jar which contains SLF4J classes, On Unix system:

Go to your WEB-INF/lib/ directory and run following command

`for i in *.jar; do jar -tvf "$i" | grep -Hsi MessageFormatter && echo "$i"; done`

This will print matching result from all jars on console.

Finally, we replaced `tika-app` jar by `tika-core` jar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the same "**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**" deploying an EAR file to **JBoss EAP 5.2**.

The logs showed:

SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]

**Logs:** (server.log)

```
2018-11-05 09:59:46,382 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2018-11-05 09:59:46,395 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
2018-11-05 09:59:46,395 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
2018-11-05 09:59:46,402 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/common-scheduling/services]] (main) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at
```

**Problem:**

The problem was having two different versions of slf4j-api jars on the classpath. (slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar, slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar)

**Resolution:**

1. I ran "mvn dependency:tree" to find the location of the transitive dependency.
2. Then, I added a maven exclusion tag to exclude the undesired artifact version.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with Spark Application.
It is caused when different versions are mixed.

We should use something like this :

```
 "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.30" % Test,
 "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.30" % Test,
```