# maven dependency + local jar in build path = slf4j conflict

Tags: java, maven, jar, spark-framework, octane-sdk

I try to use the IMPINJ Octane SDK Java which comes as a jar including all needed dependencies together with Spark Framework in a maven project. To include the Spark Framework I use maven and the Octane SDK jar is added to the build path. My pom.xml has only the spark dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Every time I try to run the program I get to following error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.log(JettyAwareLogger.java:619)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.info(JettyAwareLogger.java:314)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:74)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.initialized(Log.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:298)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:288)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.<clinit>(AbstractLifeCycle.java:35)
at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyFactory.create(EmbeddedJettyFactory.java:34)
at spark.embeddedserver.EmbeddedServers.create(EmbeddedServers.java:57)
at spark.Service.lambda$init$0(Service.java:342)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The Octane SDK comes with slf4j and the Spark Framework also has slf4j as a dependency but they have different versions. I found the following thread [NoSuchMethodError with SLF4J API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479811/nosuchmethoderror-with-slf4j-api) but since I could remove slf4j from the jar I can't resolve the problem. How can I get this working?

I also tried to exclude slf4j in the pom but it did not work either:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT (SOLUTION):
I extracted the Octane SDK jar, removed slf4j and compressed it back to a jar.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that sparks requires slf4j 1.7.13.
Then, you add Octane to the classpath (not through a maven dependency) and this Octane jar contains older classes of slf4j.

I just downloaded Octane to see for myself. I notice it include 2 versions:

- OctaneSDKJava-1.22.0.30.jar
- OctaneSDKJava-1.22.0.30-jar-with-dependencies.jar

You need to use OctaneSDKJava-1.22.0.30.jar and manually include all other dependencies but NOT the slf4j one (or the opposite, use OctaneSDKJava-1.22.0.30-jar-with-dependencies.jar and remove slf4j).

---

## EDIT to answer a question in the comments:

I opened the latest **OctaneSDKJava-1.26.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.zip**, which contains a README.txt with the following details:

> ## DEPENDENCIES
>
> **RUNTIME DEPENDENCIES**
>
> - jdom        1.0         http://www.jdom.org
> - log4j       1.2.15      http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html
> - jargs       1.0         http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=33024
> - mina        1.1.7       http://mina.apache.org
> - slf4j-log4j12 1.5.0         http://www.slf4j.org
> - slf4j-api 1.5.0         http://www.slf4j.org
> - xerces-j  2.4.0         http://xerces.apache.org/
>
> **COMPILE DEPENDENCIES**
>
> - velocity-dep        1.5     http://velocity.apache.org
> - jalopy              0.3.1   http://jalopy.sourceforge.net
> - jdom                1.0     http://www.jdom.org
> - log4j               1.2.15  http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html
> - commons-collection  3.2     http://commons.apache.org
> - commons-configuration 1.5   http://commons.apache.org
> - commons-lang        2.3     http://commons.apache.org
> - common-logging      1.1.1   http://commons.apache.org
>
> JAXB RI dependencies including:
>
> - jaxb-xjc            2.0     https://jaxb.dev.java.net/
> - jaxb-impl           2.0     https://jaxb.dev.java.net/
> - jaxb-api            2.0     https://jaxb.dev.java.net/
> - activation          2.0     https://jaxb.dev.java.net/
> - jsr173_1.0_api      2.0     https://jaxb.dev.java.net/
>
> The five above jaxb dependencies are available in a single jar "JAXB
>   RI" from https://jaxb.dev.java.net/. Execute this jar (doubleclick
>   windows, "java -jar " all other platforms) and copy the
>   individual jars to the LTKJava/lib directory) plus above runtime
>   dependencies
>
> **TEST DEPENDENCIES**
>
> - JUnit       4.4         http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=15278
>     plus above dependencies note that the junit dependency needs to be
>     placed in the ANT_HOME/lib directory

Comment: `[INFO] \- com.sparkjava:spark-core:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO]    \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile` this is the ouput. I extracted the octane SDK Jar and found slf4j 1.5.0

Comment: oh I see.. Octane is not added to the classpath as a dependency. And it comes with its own jars... So your problem/solution is rather at runtime, not build time..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying this at the moment.

Comment: @alexbt - do you have a list of the other dependencies that the octane sdk needs?